# Web Audio Api : navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ---> Error:NotReadableError: Concurrent mic process limit

Tags: firefox, web-audio-api, getusermedia, navigator, mediadevices

I am developing a 3D environment that connects two microphones with a specific geometry in my scene , runs locally.
I want to be able to switch between which microphone is being used ( when I press key A use mic1 and when I press key B use mic 2 ).
The error I get is :
Firefox ----> Error:NotReadableError: Concurrent mic process limit.
Chrome -> no Error, it just doesn't switch devices

How can I fix that ? I tried to stop the stream but maybe I am not doing it right , any suggestions ?

```
async function openMic(nodein){ 

 // inputDevices is an array with the deviceIds
 await  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ({audio: { deviceId: {exact: 
                         inputDevices[nodein]}}, video: false}) 
 
    .then(function(stream) {
    console.log('THE DEVICE IS: '+ thisdev);    

    //soundNodesArray has objects that represent different sources
    soundNodesArray[nodein].source=context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

    //making our source a stream connect source with Gain node
    soundNodesArray[nodein].source.connect(soundNodesArray[nodein].volume);
                
    //connect Gain node with Panner node                     
    soundNodesArray[nodein].volume.connect(soundNodesArray[nodein].panner);
                
    //connect the Panner Node with the Destination node                  
    soundNodesArray[nodein].panner.connect(context.destination);
 })
.catch(function(e){
    alert('Error:'+e);
    });
        
}
```

For stopping the track I call this function first :

```
    async function closeMic(nodeout) {
await   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false})
    .then(function(mediaStream) {
        const tracks = mediaStream.getTracks();
          
        tracks.forEach(function(track) {
        track.stop();
        console.log('STOPPED STREAM ?????????');
        });
    })
  
    soundNodesArray[nodeout].source = null;
  }
enter code here
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] your question to show us the code which switches microphones. Don't forget to `.stop()` all the tracks in the stream when you stop using a microphone.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59068146/navigator-mediadevices-getusermedia-api-rejecting-with-error-notreadableerror/67754094. I added an answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await` ... `.then()` is not correct.

To open up your stream, do something like this.

```js
let stream  // keep the stream so you can stop it later.
async function openMic(nodein){ 
  try {
    // inputDevices is an array with the deviceIds
   stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia (
                 {audio: { deviceId: {exact: inputDevices[nodein]}},
                  video: false}) 
 
   //soundNodesArray has objects that represent different sources
   soundNodesArray[nodein].source=context.createMediaStreamSource(stream)

   ...
  } catch (e) {
    alert('Error:' + e)
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

Later, to stop the stream stop all its tracks and forget it exists. Don't use `.getUserMedia()` to try to get another stream to stop. Instead stop the one you already have.

```js
const tracks = stream.getTracks()
tracks.forEach(track => {track.stop()})
stream = undefined
```

I'm not familiar with the AudioContext stuff; you may have to stop that stuff too before starting a new stream.

It's best to stop one stream before using `getUserMedia()` to start another. Some browsers allow you to start one stream before stopping another. Others don't.

Comment: Thank you ! I tried the changes , the part that wasn't working after all was my attempt to stop the stream .

Comment: `await stream =` is wrong, since it makes `stream` a promise. You want `stream = await `.

Comment: D'oh! (facepalm) you are right. Thanks for the correction, @jib